# Laravel Eloquent creating categories for posts

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables posts, categories and post_category. There are 2 categories for example books(1) and magazines(2) for the post. I create the post and choose two categories books and magazines I wanted to save the post_id and also the categories_id in the post_category table how do I insert the two categories in different row and how can i get the id of the post when submitted? btw I tried adding category_id in post table as an array but I'm having a hard time query a single id for the category.

[image]

Comment: Have you setup relations on `Post` and `Category` model? Both are `belongsToMany` with provided table name, because it doesn't follow the convention (`category_post` - alphabetical order, singular)

Comment: There seems to be small typo in your PostCategoryTable picture as the id in the first column shouldn't be 1 in both rows, but 1 and 2.

Comment: yes sorry about that it should be 2 not 1

Answer (score 0):

use insert command

```
$param = array(
        array('post_id' => '1', 'category_id' => 1),
        array('post_id' => '1', 'category_id' => 2),
);

DB::table('post')->insertGetId($param);
```

**NOTE !** it ignores timestamp

[LINK HERE](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#inserts)

Comment: Your code is via the Query Builder, not Eloquent ;-)

Comment: you are write @trizz ... :) ... so ?

Comment: what if I only selected 1 category?

Comment: you should build an array and pass as parameter to insertGetId function

Comment: This is definitely wrong. it's about inserting into pivot table, not posts, and even so, this is far from the easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eloquent and you have set the relationships on your models properly, you can use the `attach()` method on a models relation, [to insert new records on the pivot table](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models).

```
$post = Post::create(['title' => 'Hello Second World']);
$post->categories()->attach([1,2]); // Attaching Category IDs to pivot table
echo $post->id; // Getting the ID
```

**Followup:**

The `attach()` method will only create new records on the pivot table according to the parameters passed, **but will not create new instances of the related model**

To achieve this you would need to pass the model to the `save()` method on the relation:

```
$post = Post::create(['title' => 'Hello World']);
$post->categories()->save(Category::create(['category' => 'Leaflets']));
```

*Thanks to [**deczo**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/784588/deczo) for clarifying this*

Comment: Any comments why this one is downvoted? I read through the question multiple times and actually thought I understood it right.

Comment: SE should provide the option to see who is down voting or up voting, anybody knows how to see it

Comment: Probably because attach won't save a newly instantiated Model, but you never know.. However your code is what the OP needs, so here's my +. I'd suggest only adding that `create` already saved the post, before invoking `attach` on the relation.

Comment: @deczo `Probably because attach won't save a newly instantiated Model` would you mind to explain that to me? :) `attach()` is going to insert new records according to the parameters passed. Why would it need to save the Model, or do you mean something else here? Thanks for the tip, I'll add it

Comment: You linked `insert a related model`, what `attach` can't do. It requires the related model to 'exist', ie. to be saved before. Meaning: `$model = new Model([..]); $parent->relation()->attach($model);` will not work, but `$parent->relation()->save($model)` will.

Comment: @deczo okay now I got what you meant. I added it and credited you. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$post = new Post();
$post->title = 'Hello new post';
$post->save();
$category_ids = $input['category_id']; //html name in array 
$post_cat_data = array();
foreach($category_ids as $index => $value) {
    if (!empty($value)) {           
        $post_cat_data[] = [            
        'category_id' => $value,            
       ];
    }       
 }                  
$post->post_category()->createMany($post_cat_data);
```